# Does iOS 11.3 have the Scan Credit Card feature?

Tags: ios, safari

So, Safari supposedly offers a Scan Credit Scan feature.

This feature works and it's available on my IPad 2nd Generation (Safari 601.1)(AppleWebKit/601.1.46) (iOS Version 9.3.5)

**But**..

On my Apple MH182LL/A iPad Air 2 9.7 the same feature doesn't work (Safari 604.1) (iOS 11.3).

What i have tried:

- Disabling the passcode & touch id
- Enabling Camera & Microphone Access to the Safari App (Settings>>Safari>>Camera & Microphone Access)
- Added a Credit Card via Scanning by going to (Settings>>Safari>>Saved Credit Cards>>Add Credit Card>>Use Camera (**It works)**

Something that i've noticed... (Settings >> Privacy >> Camera >> The **Safari App** it's not included among all the other apps that have access to the camera.)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlQje.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the solution was :
Settings >> Keyboards >> Enable Shortcuts